# How to disable expo developer menu trigger (or change trigger)?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I need to use vertical shaking trigger in my app, but Expo's Developer Menu appears and there is no way to disable it showing through Expo GO options. How to remove this trigger from my app?

[image: Developer Menu]